# I want to change squareLabel values in handleGesture func, but I really don't know how to

Tags: ios, swift

```
// This function creates the design of the squares inside of our Game Board View in storyboard
func createSquare (item: UIView) -> UILabel {
    let squareLabel = UILabel()
    
    //Setting board view squares size, colors and other attributes
    squareLabel.frame = CGRect(x: xY, y: yX, width: square.squareWidth, height: square.squareHeight)
    
    squareLabel.text = ""
    squareLabel.textAlignment = .center
    squareLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    squareLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
    
    //isUserInteractionEnabled is set to true so that you can tap
    squareLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    squareLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    
    //To add tap recognizers on our squares in Game Board View 
    let labelTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleGesture))
    squareLabel.addGestureRecognizer(labelTap)
    
    return squareLabel
}

@objc func handleGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil){
    
    if sender?.state == .ended {
        print("TAPPEDY TAP")
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to your label from the gesture recognizer in your action method.

See this example:

```
    @objc func handleGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil){
        
        if sender?.state == .ended {
            print("TAPPEDY TAP")

            sender?.view?.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: CGFloat(drand48()), saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
```